# How to get the amount of field in a embed in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am trying to make a help command for my bot (a bit fancy)
So for that I made different categories for the commands! like this-

```
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.title = ":computer: **Help Centre: Meta!**"
    embed.description=":pen_ballpoint: Type `am:[command]` to use a command!"
    embed.add_field(name="am:hi",value="To say hi to me!")
    embed.add_field(name="am:report [issue]",value="To report a bug/issue about the bot!")
    embed.add_field(name='am:feedback [feedback\suggestion]',value="To sent a feedback or suggestion to my cretor!")
    embed.colour = discord.Colour.green()
    embed.set_footer(text="Among Us help centre!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)


async def wikipe(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.title = ":computer: **Help Centre: Wiki!**"
    embed.description=":pen_ballpoint: Type `am:[command]` to use a command!"
    embed.add_field(name="am:wiki [query]",value="To know more about among us game!")
    embed.add_field(name="am:find [query]",value="To find anything other than Among Us!")
    embed.colour = discord.Colour.green()
    embed.set_footer(text="Among Us help centre!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

async def tools(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.title = ":computer: **Help Centre: Tools!**"
    embed.description=":pen_ballpoint: Type `am:[command]` to use a command!"
    embed.add_field(name="am:dm [@user]\n[message]",value="To send an instant message to anyone from the server!")
    embed.colour = discord.Colour.green()
    embed.set_footer(text="Among Us help centre!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

So now I need the number of fields in each and every categories (i.e. no. of commands in each category)!
I made a function. Something like this-

```
def fields(cate):
    i=0
    for emb in cate:
        for fields in emb.fields:
            i+=1
```

But I am getting an error, can anyone of you help me??
Error is -

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 93, in help
    embed.add_field(name="Meta",value = str(fields(meta)))
  File "main.py", line 81, in fields
    for emb in cate:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable```
````

Comment: Please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there is an error is stated in the traceback - you are trying to iterate over a function.

So wherever you are calling `fields()` you are accidentally passing a function instead of an iterable object (like a `list`).

Comment: So how can I get the number of fields?